# Intellij AWS Tooltkit Settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea

Working on creating an AWS serverless lambda function using Intellij as my IDE.  After installing all the pre-requisite programs (AWS CLI V2, AWS SAM CLI, docker, and AWS Toolkit for Intellij), I opened up Intellij and went to configure the Settings -> Tools -> AWS settings:
- SAM CLI executable
- cloud-debug CLI executable

I have searched all over and cannot find what the exact executable should be for these two.  I did notice that there are two new entries in my PATH variable so I am assuming it's something in one of these two paths:
- C:\Programming\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\
- C:\Programming\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any update on what the path for cloud-debug should be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAM CLI executable can be obtained here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html

The SAM CLI executable path should be:

- c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd

I'm still trying to figure what "cloud-debug CLI executable" is for. Perhaps a new feature?

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-36215 (Something .NET related?)
  (I'll update if I ever find out)

Update 1

- The Intellij AWS toolkit plugin welcome page talks about being able to debug code in Amazon ECS clusters (which is in beta)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/welcome.html#welcome-using